# Restricting access to a website 

Tags: security, web-server

How to restrict users to go to my site only by using the domain name not by the IP address.

```
example.
WWW.fun.com - allow
http://172.20.145.78 - don allow.
```

Please help

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: Since this is a web server configuration issue, it should probably be posted on serverfault. Also, the "accessibility" tag is a bit misleading here.

Answer (score 1):

Set a virtualhost name-based. If you are using apache, read [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
ServerName ip.add.re.ss
DocumentRoot /path/to/somewhere/else
<Directory /path/to/somewhere/else>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.fun.com
ServerAlias fun.com *.fun.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/your/webroot
</VirtualHost>
```

That should do it.